# Which translation is best for 'quid pro quo'?

Tags: usage

There should always be a quid pro quo.
总是应该有个？？？（条件：Maybe I need 条件： condition）

quid pro quo: 抵偿物； 补偿物； 相等物； 代用品; 对价

Comment: jukuu：１３ example  sentences，iciba 5 example sentences (esp. 互通有无)

Answer (score 2):

"quid pro quo " means "a favor or advantage granted or expected in return of something". A literal translation would be 对等交换 (equal exchange)

There are some Chinese idioms similar to it

有來有往 (things go both way)

投桃报李 (repay favor with favor)

礼尚往来 (repay in kind)

> There should always be a quid pro quo. 总是应该有个 ? ? ?

总是应该有个"对等交换" (literal)

总是应该有个"礼尚往来" (idiomatic)

Comment: Good answer! One thing you want to be more careful may be that use traditional or simplified Chinese, not both.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can translate it into a Chinese saying

> 天下没有免费的午餐。

The literal translation of it is there is no free lunch.

Comment: should be "lunch"

Comment: @EmmaXL thank you, I have changed the mistake

Comment: @Gangosa Hoped has the help to you:)

Comment: Is this sentence really from OLD Chinese? In English the origin is unknown but apparently not old http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/tanstaafl.html It has the help to me :)!

Comment: @Gangosa Sorry about it, I search it just now.It is not from old Chinese.By the way,the original may be a western proverb.

Comment: It's ok to write this in an article. But if you are talking or writing to a friend, suggesting a favor for a favor, I think this is a little impolite.